# How do I make something like rss2gif?

Tags: php, rss

I would like to know how I can create something like the rss2gif site: http://www.studentomat.de/rss2gif/.

Please note that I only want to do this for one of my websites and not allow other people to put their own URL in.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Just don't. There are a couple problems, notably 1) people with images disabled and blind people can't access the content and 2) you can't select the text and 3) it's a waste of processing power. What's wrong with simple text and CSS?

Comment: What I want to be able to do is show the latest post from my blog on forums that doesn't allow you you use flash or anything like that.

Comment: So, how about JavaScript and [Ajax](http://google.com/search?q=Ajax+tutorial+javascript)? Infinitely easier...

Comment: @Pablo: See comment #1 and paragraph #2.

Comment: The issue here is that I can't put javascript or HTML in my forun sig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out image functions from php.net u can see the examples of how to create image and write something on it.. functions names are "imagecreatefromjpeg ... and etc"

Comment: I got one idea on how I could do this, I found a plugin for mybb (Userbar v2.2) and does what I'm looking at doing. While it does not have everything that I need, it would be a good start :)